# How to pass multiple arguments into a Ruby method

Tags: ruby

Passing one argument at a time into the parser method works. 
More than one and it generates "syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')' (SyntaxError)"

```
$array = []
array_1 = %w(tuna salmon herring)
array_2 = %w(crow owl eagle dove)

def parser (*argument)
  argument.each do |item|
    $array << item
  end
end

parser (array_1, array_2) # taking multiple arguments generates error
$array.flatten!
puts $array
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the space before the parens. Remove it. Instead of treating `array_1` and `array_2` as args, it's treating it as a parenthesized expression (with the whole expression being one arg) and complaining about the comma. Your code should look like

```
parser(array_1, array_2)
```

Incidentally, Ruby 1.8.7 seems to simply emit a warning about this before behaving correctly.

Comment: guess they changed behavior at 1.9 time?

Comment: @rogerdpack: Presumably so. I don't have Ruby 1.9 installed so I can't test.